# How to change the layout of the CreateUserWizard control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0

How to change just the layout (template) of the CreateUserWizard control programmatically? I would to define another layout (not using the horrid table) but continue to use all the event handling and the creation of the user of the CreateUserWizard control.
Just for reference, the following code doesn't work, and produces an unexpected result not representing my Template at all. The "InstantiateIn" method of the ITemplate is not called.

```
public partial class b : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateUserWizard createUserWizard = new CreateUserWizard();
            createUserWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplate = new Template();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(createUserWizard);
        }
    }

    public class Template : ITemplate
    {
        void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "UserName" });
            container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Password" });
            container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "ConfirmPassword" });
            container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Email" });
            container.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder() { ID = "ErrorMessage" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for adding it programmaticaly or just to get rid of tabular format? You can customize the layout in markup as per your need. And with 4.0 asp.net doesn't render it as table any more.

Comment: @gbs: Thanks for your suggestion, but there is no mark-up because the control will end up in a pre-compiled dll. Also I'm not merely trying to get rid of the table, I am programmatically building the ContentTemplate from a parsed XML file. So the layout will be highly variable. I used a similar approach for the Login control and that works perfectly. But the Login control calls the InstantiateIn method of the ITemplate, whereas the CreateUserWizard does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why this works, but it does:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateUserWizard createUserWizard = new CreateUserWizard();

        /* Difference Starts Here */
        CreateUserWizardStep createUserWizardStep = new CreateUserWizardStep();
        createUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate = new Template();
        createUserWizard.WizardSteps.Add(createUserWizardStep);
        /* End Difference */

        Panel1.Controls.Add(createUserWizard);
    }
}

public class Template : ITemplate
{
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "UserName" });
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Password" });
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Question" });
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Answer" });
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "ConfirmPassword" });
        container.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "Email" });
        container.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder() { ID = "ErrorMessage" });
    }
}
```

What I did was add a CreateUserWizard control to a page, added a blank ContentTemplate, and followed the instructions for [debugging generated ASP.NET code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/02/03/debugging-asp-net-generated-code.aspx) to reverse engineer what the ASP.NET code generator does.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Greg, but I believe I tried something similar to this and it gives an error saying that the CreateUserWizard can have only 1 CreateUserWizardStep. Also the CreateUserWizard.CreateUserStep is readonly so you cannot create a new one and replace the current one.

Comment: Well, worst case scenario you could go through the same steps with the generated code to figure out what asp.net is doing to make it work.

Comment: I'll have a look into the "debugging generated ASP.net code" article. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I managed to get it working following your advice and tips. So your answer is correct. Better late than never, I guess! :)